# Google Vision API Score and Topicality meaning

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I am working on the Google Cloud Vision API.

After I process image into some list of labels, I can see the scores and topicalities of each of the labels in the image.

I get scores and topicalities are showing relationship between label and image.

However, I am not sure how they are getting these numbers.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#EntityAnnotation

in the link, it only said

Score: overall score of the result. Rang [0,1]

Topicality: Relevancy of the ICA (Image Content Annotation) label to the image

Moreover, how they are different from each other?
When I run the program, score and topicality are always same for all labels.

Answer (score 2):

These "score" and "topicality" fields always display the same value.There is an existing bug on this Vision API functionality.

I recommend you to take a look on this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/117855698) that has been created to review this issue, as well as the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes) documentation of Vision API to keep the track of the new functionalities added to the service.

You can “STAR” the issue to receive automatic updates on the progress and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Comment: This is exactly same answer that I saw in other stackoverflow post that is posted in 2018. They did not fixed the bug for 5 years? eventhough they know th e issue?